# iframe force links to open in the current window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm looking for a solution that allows any links that are clicked inside an iframe to open in the window containing the iframe.

people have suggested using:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

However, i don't have access to the source of the iframe

Please could you help me achieve a solution or point me in the right direction, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance, Josh

Comment: Try **target blank**? `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">link…</a>`

Comment: I don't have access to the iframe targets source unfortunately

Comment: @FabianPicone `target="_blank"` is for for opening in a new tab .

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not possible because of the the [`Same Origin Policy`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) :(

If you did have access to the source you could use [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to manipulate the contents of the `iframe`.

Comment: I didn't really want to have to edit the webpage shown in the iframe, what would you suggest to be the least invasive method of getting it to work in the iframe without affecting the website?

Comment: Just like @josh2205 said. `target='_blank'` would be your best option here, but again it's only if it's on the same domain. If the iframe is going to `whatever.com` it's not possible because of the [`Same Origin Policy`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).